# rviz problem with server x

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
When I want to run empty rviz (rosrun rviz rviz) I get the following error
rviz: cannot connect to X server.
Do somebody know what to do?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45509/rviz-problem-with-server-x/) by [harke](https://answers.ros.org/users/3357/harke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess you do not have an X server running. Are you maybe trying to run it inside an ssh connection or not inside a terminal in a graphical environment such as Ubuntu's Unity?

If you want to run rviz locally but visualize data from a robot, just set the variable ROS_MASTER_URI on your pc correctly. Have a look [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup) for more information.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1